# Azure Shared Caching and Co-located Caching in the same project

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

So I was wondering if it was possible to use both Azure Shared caching and the new co-located cache for a web role? I want to store session state in the old Azure Shared Cache to preserve session state between deployments of the application using VIP swap. I would like to use the new co-located cache for caching values in-memory that are accessed quite frequently but are not changed often in the database, therefore making them ideal to cache with the new co-located cache and notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to get both to work. It seems that one version of caching requires the 101.0.0.0 versions of Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching and Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache, while the other requires the 1.0.0.0 versions. This can be verified by installing the different nuget packages for Azure Caching and Azure Shared Caching. If someone does know how to get both running, please post a solution here.

I've migrated my session data to Azure SQL using the Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers and added the distributed cache to the project instead of using both caching methods.

Answer (score 1):

Should work just fine - just used different names for the caches in the config section:

```
<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="colocated">
       <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="[cache cluster role name]" />
    </dataCacheClient>
    <dataCacheClient name="shared">
       <hosts>
           <host name="yourcachename.cache.windows.net" cachePort="22233" />
       </hosts>
    </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>
```

and in code:

```
DataCache coloCache = new DataCache("colocated");
DataCache sharedcache = new DataCache("shared");
```

and in your session config:

```
<!-- Windows Azure Caching session state provider -->
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" 
      type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache"
      cacheName="shared" 
      dataCacheClientName="shared" 
      applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: Seems like I have some dll mismatch issues when I do this. I'm looking into if I can find the right combinations.

Comment: shared caching may be going away too - rumor mill!

Comment: Don't use shared caching, it's, er... not very good. If you need to persist between deployments, get your cache into blobs (or something) and reload

Comment: @SimonMunro Sounds good in theory, but do you have any simple way to persist the cache to blob storage between deployments?

Comment: You can list all of the objects in the cache ([DataCache.GetObjectsByTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.datacache.getobjectsbytag(v=azure.10).aspx])), write them out to a blob, and load them when an instance starts. Session state may be tricker though - maybe write a session state provider that can use blob and cache as a store (if it can't find object in cache it loads from blobs), which is not a bad idea anyway as if a cache gets full data drops off anyway

Comment: @SimonMunro I'm really only worried about persisting session state between deployments, the regular cache can get regenerated. I just don't want users to get logged out. I'll look into a custom session state provider but that seems like it might take a decent amount of work.

Comment: You can always run your own memcached cluster. A couple of extra small linux VMs should work well. Lots of community support/guidance to help you get going quickly.

Comment: Another thing to remember about a VIP swap - technically, the user should stay on the same instance/session unless you delete instances right after a swap.  The load balancer should gracefully drain the sessions from the old instances.

Comment: @viperguynaz Well we are currently making major changes, some of which may be breaking. In this case we wouldn't want the users to continue to be linked to the previous instances. I've posted my solution and will probably close this question tomorrow. Gave you a +1 for the useful comments, I decided it is best to get off shared caching regardless.